# Refresh all files in buffer from disk in vim

Tags: git, vim, buffer

The command to refresh a file from version on disk is `:e!`

How can I do the same for all files in the buffer?

Background: I need that because I am using git with multiple branches with one vim open that contains a buffer. When I checkout a branch, I would like to have vim refresh.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Read the documentation for `bufdo`, it should do what you want.

Comment: ok great so, :bufdo e! will do that. But there is a prompt Load (Y/N) each time. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Use `set noconfirm` before using the `bufdo` command (`set confirm` afterwards to reanable).

Comment: I would use `bufdo e` (no exclamation mark) instead of `bufdo e!` as it can detect unsaved changes where there should be none, just to be on the safe side

Comment: `bufdo e` curiously leaves all the buffers un-syntax-highlighted

Comment: @StevenLu Check PaulFenney's answer below.

Comment: Why are people voting this up? It's not only not an answer, but the direction it leads you means your syntax highlighting gets disabled after reload.

Comment: run `:syntax on` to re-enable syntax highlighting

Comment: Downvoting, because @paulfenney answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @dmitry-minkovsky Because this is the only correct answer to the question asked. And that is useful in a broader context then just files updated in the background.

Answer (score 126):

The `:checkt[ime]` command is designed for this very purpose.

It will prompt you to reload any buffers that have changed; if you wish to skip the prompt, you can do `:set autoread` beforehand (you'll still get a prompt on buffers with local unsaved changes).

It also avoids the syntax highlighting issue mentioned by Steven Lu on the accepted answer; [`:bufdo` turns off syntax highlighting by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514266/431606).

Found via: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Bug-report-bufdo-e-breaking-syntax-highlighting-on-displayed-buffers-tp1209995p1209998.html

Comment: :set autoread   FTW

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I ended up putting in my .vimrc:

```
fun! PullAndRefresh()
  set noconfirm
  !git pull
  bufdo e!
  set confirm
endfun

nmap <leader>gr call PullAndRefresh()
```

Answer (score 7):

From `:help autoread`:

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again. When the file has been deleted this is not done.

If, like me, you just want to *always passively* reload stale-but-unmodified buffers, then this seems like it should get the job done.

However the final detail is *when* vim notices the stale buffer.  That can be forced with `checktime`.  If you have [focus events set up](https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim), then we can run `checktime` whenever we gain focus like so:

```
set autoread
autocmd FocusGained * checktime
```

[This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2731) also has some interesting details.

Answer (score 2):

As @Matthew S Mentioned here https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/462,
you can use:

```
:set noconfirm
:bufdo !e
:set confirm
```