# Refresh Vim buffer

Tags: vim

I'm editing HTML files.
I use this keymap to launch firefox to preview the page:

```
map <F6> :update<CR>:silent !xdg-open %:p<CR>
```

But after this command, the Vim window becomes completely black.
I need to scroll every line to make it appear again.

So I want to write a function to fresh the buffer. Here's what i did:

```
function! Refresh()                                                                                                                                               
    " code
    set noconfirm
    bufdo e!
    set confirm
endfunction

nmap <F5> :call Refresh()<CR>
```

I got the idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272007/refresh-all-files-in-buffer-from-disk-in-vim).
But it doesn't work.

Comment: If I press Ctrl+L it redraws.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to redraw the screen. You can also use `:redraw`.

Check the [help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#CTRL-L) on these.

Comment: Redrawing the screen is not the same as refreshing (reloading) the buffer.

Comment: How do I refresh the buffer tho?

Answer (score 8):

How about adding a "redraw" do your function (which does the same as ctrl-L)

```
:redr[aw][!]    Redraw the screen right now.  When ! is included it is
                cleared first.
                Useful to update the screen halfway executing a script
                or function.  Also when halfway a mapping and
                'lazyredraw' is set.
```

Comment: for some reason, `:redr` didn't refresh my screen, but CtrlL did. Wonder why.

Comment: What if you append an exclamation mark to the end? Example: `:redr!`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my bindings for previewing HTML documents with resolved empty screen issue:

`autocmd BufRead *.html map <F5> :exe ':silent !open -a /Applications/Firefox.app %'<CR>:redr!<CR>`

I prefer use `autocmd` for bindings, because I can map same key for various things depending what type of file I am working in. For example with autocmd I can map F5 for previewing document in Firefox on html-files and map same key F5 on js-files for executing node.