# filetype setting lost after reloading all files in buffer

Tags: vim

After running `:bufdo e!`
All my files lose their filetype setting and I have to manually run `:set ft=XXX` in each file.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Running `:bufdo set ft=XXX` doesn't work and I don't want to set all files to the same filetype at any rate.

Cheers.

Comment: From the vim docs: _Note: While this command is executing, the Syntax 
autocommand event is disabled by adding it to 'eventignore'.  This considerably speeds up editing each buffer._

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce your issue unless I turn automatic filetype detection off, do you have `:filetype on`?

Comment: actually, running ':set ft?' on files that have lost their syntax highlighting shows that the filetype is correctly set! Is that what the vim docs are referring to?

Comment: Ok, reproduced it now, running `syntax on` on each buffer restores the highlighting...  You might have to write a vim function if you want to do this for all buffers though since `bufdo` won't do it for obvious reasons.

Comment: it seems I just have to run `syntax on` on one buffer to restore syntax highlighting on all buffers. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice it worked for all buffers (since I was only testing with two :-)

Comment: I've added this as an answer for posterity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix this automatically via the following autocmd:

```
" Enable syntax highlighting when buffers were loaded through :bufdo, which
" disables the Syntax autocmd event to speed up processing.
augroup EnableSyntaxHighlighting
    " Filetype processing does happen, so we can detect a buffer initially
    " loaded during :bufdo through a set filetype, but missing b:current_syntax.
    " Also don't do this when the user explicitly turned off syntax highlighting
    " via :syntax off.
    " Note: Must allow nesting of autocmds so that the :syntax enable triggers
    " the ColorScheme event. Otherwise, some highlighting groups may not be
    " restored properly.
    autocmd! BufWinEnter * nested if exists('syntax_on') && ! exists('b:current_syntax') && ! empty(&l:filetype) | syntax enable | endif

    " The above does not handle reloading via :bufdo edit!, because the
    " b:current_syntax variable is not cleared by that. During the :bufdo,
    " 'eventignore' contains "Syntax", so this can be used to detect this
    " situation when the file is re-read into the buffer. Due to the
    " 'eventignore', an immediate :syntax enable is ignored, but by clearing
    " b:current_syntax, the above handler will do this when the reloaded buffer
    " is displayed in a window again.
    autocmd! BufRead * if exists('syntax_on') && exists('b:current_syntax') && ! empty(&l:filetype) && index(split(&eventignore, ','), 'Syntax') != -1 | unlet! b:current_syntax | endif
augroup END
```

**Edit**: Add autocmd nesting for proper restore of highlight groups and handle buffer reloads, as the question explicitly asked for this.

Comment: This seems to only work the first time I run `bufdo e!`. If I run it again, the other files in the buffer lose syntax highlighting.

Comment: @centerback: My main use case was `:bufdo %s... | update`; it seems that buffer reloads must be handled explicitly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This restores the default filetype syntax, however it does not restore some customized syntax setting from my vimrc. Is there a "correct" way to set a "highlight GROUP" color in the vimrc so it will be restored?

Comment: Answering my own comment, the solution was to put my `match`, `syntax` and `highlight` commands in an `autocmd` statement so the are reapplied when highlighting is enabled.

Answer (score 17):

The `bufdo` command doesn't update syntax hightlighting for performance reasons:

From vim docs:

*Note: While this command is executing, the Syntax autocommand event is disabled by adding it to 'eventignore'. This considerably speeds up editing each buffer*

You can update the syntax highlighting for affected buffers by re-running:

`:syntax on`

Comment: Nope.   `:syntax on` did not update the changes in my `$HOME/.vim/syntax/custom.vim` file.

Answer (score 6):

If you're checking for changed files (for example after switching branches in your VCS) then `:checktime` may be a more appropriate solution than `:bufdo e!` - it's designed for this purpose and doesn't have the syntax highlighting issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer for any time a file (buffer) is modified outside of Vim. Like Paul said, an example would be when switching between branches.