# Open all files in a directory in different Vim windows

Tags: vim

Writing Rails apps means juggling a lot of files. Thank the gods for versatile text editors with multiple buffers, windows and tabs!

I am trying to edit all files in a directory in a new window (in vim, not in gnome). Is there a way to do this with a one-line from within vim? I've been trying every trick I know, but they are to no help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:args` to add all your files to the argument list and `:argdo` to perform an action, here we do `:sp filename` on each item of the list.

```
:args *.js | argdo sp
```

See `:h :args` and `:h :argdo`.

Comment: also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485981/syntax-highlighting-is-not-turned-on-in-vim-when-opening-multiple-files-using-ar) if you have syntax highlighting problems afterwards.