# Vim split causes syntax highlight to turn on

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a function to cause vim to open the relative header/source file in a split window.

What I have works (see below) apart from the file it opens in the split doesn't have syntax highlighting.

```
function! SplitOther()
    let s:fname = expand("%:p:r")

    if expand("%:e") == "h"
        set splitright
        exe "vsplit" fnameescape(s:fname . ".cpp")
    elseif expand("%:e") == "cpp"
        set nosplitright
        exe "vsplit" fnameescape(s:fname . ".h")
    endif
endfunction

autocmd! BufReadPost *.h,*.cpp call SplitOther()
```

I have tried appending `syntax on` to the command (just before the `endfunction`) but that doesn't seem to want to work.

I think it happens when the file isn't in a buffer before splitting? I'm not 100% sure though.

## Edit

I change my function to have allow the definition of file pairs, I'm not sure if it will change my question at all so here's the extended version:

```
function! SplitOther()
    let s:pairs = [ [ "h", "cpp" ], [ "vert", "frag" ] ]
    let s:fname = expand("%:p:r")

    for [s:left, s:right] in s:pairs
        if expand("%:e") == s:left
            set splitright
            exe "vsplit" fnameescape(s:fname . "." . s:right)
        elseif expand("%:e") == s:right
            set nosplitright
            exe "vsplit" fnameescape(s:fname . "." . s:left)
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

autocmd! BufReadPost * call SplitOther()
```

Comment: It's working without `autocmd!`, i.e. using a map or something. Does it have to be automatic? I use `<leader>le` for this.

Comment: The automation was more to make life easier

Comment: Aye, I can understand that, although I prefer to not have something like this being forced automatically, thus using an easy bind instead. Anyway, there's nothing wrong with your function, it's because of `autocmd`.

Comment: I suspect I'm using the wrong event or something, I'll experiement

Comment: You could take a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10513583/1076493). I didn't get it to work with this use of `autocmd`, but it might give you an idea.

Comment: If I do `:windo filetype detect` on a file pair opened by this command it fixes it so I tried adding `exe "window" "filetype detect"` at the end of the function but that doesn't work??

Comment: I don't know about automation, but you may want to look here about switching to header files: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

When the file was being loaded into the vsplit it's filetype wasn't being set.

I noted that when vsplit is called the new split grabs focus and that is the window that does not have syntax highlighting so you can simply add `exe "filetype" "detect"` at the end of the function to tell vim to detect the filetype of the current window.

The result:

```
function! SplitOther()
    let s:pairs = [ [ "h", "cpp" ], [ "vert", "frag" ] ]
    let s:fname = expand("%:p:r")

    for [s:left, s:right] in s:pairs
        if expand("%:e") == s:left
            set splitright
            exe "vsplit" fnameescape(s:fname . "." . s:right) 
            break
        elseif expand("%:e") == s:right
            set nosplitright
            exe "vsplit" fnameescape(s:fname . "." . s:left)
            break
        endif
    endfor

    exe "filetype" "detect"
endfunction 

autocmd! BufRead * call SplitOther()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that filetype detection is triggered by an `autocmd`, but by default, autocommands do not nest (cp. `:help autocmd-nested`).

Also, by using `:autocmd!` with a bang, you're clearing all other such global autocmds; this might affect other customizations or plugins! You should define your own scope via `:augroup`, then it's safe. Taken together:

```
augroup MyAltSplitPlugin
    autocmd! BufReadPost * nested call SplitOther()
augroup END
```

Comment: I do have the autocommand in a group I just had quite a few commands in that augroup so I omitted it. I'll read up on the nested, thanks!